# Would you like to integrate your new app with cordova to target native ios and android is taking time with no response

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have :

```
ionic version 3.20, 
cordova version 8.0.0
```

When I  try to create an ionic project by executing the below command:

```
ionic start neewapp
```

It gives me the below response:

```
√ Creating directory .\neewapp - done!
√ Downloading and extracting blank starter - done!

? Would you like to integrate your new app with Cordova to target native iOS and Android? Yes
```

If i Give yes or no for the above statement it shows no response for too long.
I have installed android studio with all latest sdk platforms.Any help?.[image: please find the screenshot here]

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and used this command and it worked:

```
Ionic start appname blank --cordova
```

Answer (score 1):

Its basically asking you if you want to create a mobile application (android and/or iOS). If that's your intention, thens hit the y key, followed by enter. It will then ask you which platforms you want to install, type a platform name from the options and hit the enter key again.

If your intent is not to create a mobile app, then hit the n key, followed by enter and you'll be on your way to developing a single page, mobile first application.

https://www.quora.com/In-Ionic-when-I-want-to-build-my-app-and-I-write-Ionic-%E2%80%98start-my-app-tabs%E2%80%99-it-shows-me-this-message-%E2%80%98Would-you-like-to-integrate-your-new-app-with-Cordova-to-target-native-iOS-and-Android%E2%80%99-How-do-I-avoid-it

Answer (score 0):

Today that question is made with (Y/n) at the end, so maybe what was expecting the console for you to respnod was one of this options, and thats maybe why the process never finished.